# How to open .sav file on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, spss

I am trying to open my .sav file on JUpyter notebook and have tried the following (using pyreadstat) :

```
import pandas as pd
import pyreadstat

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav('filename.sav')
```

However, the error kept appearing

```
Invalid file, or file has unsupported features
```

I have also tried using pandas instead

```
df = pd.read_spss('filename.sav')
```

and have received the same error.

My pyreadstat version is 0.3.4 (initially 1.1.0 but failed as well).

Comment: is it possible the SAV file is compressed?

Comment: There are several different applications that write .sav files and each has a different format that should be read with a different package. The error suggests it is not an SPSS file, try with orher options as scipy.io.readsav or other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
import pickle
import pandas

file = open('filename.sav')
df, meta = pickle.load(file)
```

hope it works.